# Default Processing in SSAS Cube not processing the data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

I have a SSAS Cube build in Tabular Mode, when I am processing it with "Default" option changes in the data is not processing. According to this link [Processing Options in SSAS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx) should process the changed in the data. Also I am processing the cube using the SSIS Package- Analysis Services Processing Task. When I choose the particular object of the cube (dimension or partition) I get the below error

"[Analysis Services Execute DDL Task] Error: Cube cannot be processed when Analysis Services is in Tabular mode. Please process Database object instead."

when I Process the the Database objects while processing the dimensions I got the below error

"[Analysis Services Execute DDL Task] Error: The process type specified for the 'Dimension1' dimension is not valid when Analysis Services is in VertiPaq mode."

Did anybody has the solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try open SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), connect to your SSAS server and process that dimension manually (ProcessType = ProcessFull/ProcessUpdate).
Are you get error in this case?

Comment: Using SSMS I didnt see the option of "Process Update" below are the options available using SSMS to process the dimension 1. Process full 2.process default 3. Process Data 4. Process Clear 5. Process Defrag